# How to Get lyrics of song from ipod library songs

Tags: iphone, ipod, mpmediaitem

I am Accessing ipod library in iphone application and showing title, lyrics and artwork of album.. I also want to show lyrics of songs. I have added lyrics in itunes and sync it with device.But  my code is not showing lyrics ..

[Example from here](http://oleb.net/blog/2009/07/the-music-player-framework-in-the-iphone-sdk/) and code to get lyrics is :-

```
- (void)handleNowPlayingItemChanged:(id)notification {
    // Ask the music player for the current song.
    MPMediaItem *currentItem = self.musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem;

    // Display the artist, album, and song name for the now-playing media item.
    // These are all UILabels.
    self.songLabel.text   = [currentItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    self.artistLabel.text = [currentItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumArtist];
    self.albumLabel.text  = [[currentItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyLyrics]retain];    


}
```

Please Help.  Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone song lyrics access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357436/iphone-song-lyrics-access)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL* songURL = [mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL] 
AVAsset* songAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:songURL options:nil]; 
NSString* lyrics = [songAsset lyrics];
```