# MPmediaitempropertylyrics return nil

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

When i try to fetch lyrics of a song using MP Media item metadata, then media item property lyrics and media item property assert url return nil and invalid response.

Comment: Could you ever solve this?

Comment: NO mpmedia item metadata not giving lyrics, and i use api for this.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (got from this post [iPhone song lyrics access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6417682/558575))

```
NSURL* songURL = [mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
AVAsset* songAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:songURL options:nil]; 
NSString* lyrics = [songAsset lyrics];
```