# How to get MPMediaItem lyrics in swift 5

Tags: swift, swift5, mpmediaitem, apple-music, mpmediaitemcollection

I checked some of SO answers but it doesn't work for me!

I need to get lyrics for the current playing song.

I get an empty result if I simply try to get lyrics from a media item:

```
   if var music = mediaItemCollection.items as? [MPMediaItem]{
            music = Array(Set(music))
            for (_, music) in music.enumerated(){
                
                let songInfo: SongInfo = SongInfo(
                    albumTitle: music.albumTitle ?? "",
                    artistName: music.artist ?? "",
                    songTitle: music.title ?? "",
                    songId: Int(music.persistentID),
                    assetURL: music.assetURL!
                    
                )
                print(music.lyrics)
                songArr.append(songInfo)
            }
      }
```

I've tried to get lyrics through asset URL as suggested in SO answers, but it does not work.

```
let songAsset = AVURLAsset(url: music.assetURL!)
if let lyricsFromAsset = songAsset.lyrics {
    print("Lyrics from asset: \(lyricsFromAsset)")
}
```

Can somebody help with getting lyrics for the current playing song from apple music?

Comment: I think: you are using content from Apple Music, while code you found didn't. They expected local music, with all metadata readable at launch. You need an async call, using https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avasynchronouskeyvalueloading might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks!, I tried with local music too but not getting lyrics.